# Slick-greeter wont stay persistent in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, login, lightdm, login-screen

I'm running Xubuntu 20.04 and I've installed `slick-greeter`, I've also run `sudo apt-get autoremove lightdm-gtk-greeter` and yet when my computer wakes up from a sleep it still goes back to the `lightdm-gtk-greeter` despite the fact that it is no longer on my system. It works on first login but after that it won't show up

The only file I modified to get slick-greeter working was the lightdm.conf file which looks like this

```
[Seat:*]

greeter-hide-users=false greeter-session=slick-greeter greeter-show-manual-login=true

[SeatDefaults]

greeter-session=slick-greeter

greeter-hide-users=false

lastuser=true
```